# Is there a better way to get only numeric value in php array without using for loop

Tags: php

Here's the an example of array that has non-numeric value.

```
$categoryRating = 

 array:3 [
  1 => 60.0
  2 => 50.0
  5 => "in-progress"
]
```

And the result should be:

```
array:3 [
  1 => 60.0
  2 => 50.0
]
```

Here's my code:

`array_filter($categoryRating[$category->id]`

but the result is the same as unfiltered.

`$category` is just a collection where I assigned id as new key for the filtered result.

Comment: where's the code? `array_filter` + `is_numeric` should do the trick

Comment: Updated with code. @Kevin

Comment: Out of curiosity: what exactly have you tried? `array_filter` needs some kind of filter criteria

Comment: Got the answer. Thanks for your comment. @NicoHaase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit: I included the oneliner from Kevin:

```
$array = [1 => 60.0, 2 => 50.0, 5 => 'in-progress'];
$array = array_filter($array, 'is_numeric');
var_dump($array);
```

Have you tried something like:

```
array_filter($categoryRating, function($v, $k) {
    return is_numeric($v);
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH));
```

It should return an array with all numeric values in your input array, but I haven't tested it.
Maybe you just have to play around with the $callback function of [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-filter.php).

Comment: no need for an anonymous function, [one liner](https://3v4l.org/TfRus) should work just fine

Comment: Can you optimize into one liner code @Kevin ?

Answer (score 0):

Without Loop:

```
array_walk_recursive($categoryRating, function(&$value,$key){
    $value = filter_var($value,FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
});
```

Loop is here:

```
$categoryRating = [60.0,50.0,6.5,'in-progress'];
    foreach ($categoryRating as $key => $val){
        $categoryRating = array_filter($categoryRating, function($val){
            return $val != is_string($val);
        });
    }
print_r($categoryRating);
```

If the array in an array:

```
$categoryRating =
        array([
            1 => 60.0,
            2 => 50.0,
            5 => "in-progress"
        ]);
    foreach ($categoryRating as $key => $val) {
        $categoryRating = array_filter($categoryRating[0], function ($val) {

            return $val != is_string($val);
        });
    }
    echo json_encode($categoryRating);
```

Comment: "Without loop" can be a bit misleading. Even though you didn't loop yourself, the array functions all perform a loop internally.